# VF component doesn't render in HTML Email Template

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, visualforce-component, email-template

What's wrong with this Apex/Visualforce code that it returns nothing in my HTML email template? I've tried *everything*.

Controller:

```
public class EmailController {
    public Id leadId { get; set; }

    public Lead getLead() {
        Lead lead;
        lead = [SELECT Loan_Cost_Net__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leadId];
        return lead;
    }
}
```

Component:

```
<apex:component controller="EmailController" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="lId" type="Id" description="Lead ID" assignTo="{!leadId}"/>

    <apex:repeat value="{!lead.Loan_Cost_Net__c}" var="l">
        {!l}
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(l >= 0, TRUE, FALSE)}">
            <apex:outputText value="{0, number, $###,###,###}">
            <apex:param value="{!l}"/>
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(l < 0, TRUE, FALSE)}">
        <apex:outputText value="({0, number, - $###,###,###})">
            <apex:param value="{!l * -1}"/>
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

Visualforce:

```
<h2>Loan Cost for {!lead.Name}</h2>
<c:SSPEmailFormattedCosts lId="{!lead.Id}" />
```

Things like `{!lead.Name}` work outside the component, just the component itself returns nothing. How do I even diagnose this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while @cropredy's answer definitely is more well informed and useful, the actual answer to my question is: you have to select a Visualforce email template type.

Duh.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is in your repeat

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lead.Loan_Cost_Net__c}" var="l">
```

the `value=` needs to be a list, but your controller `getLead()` is returning only one Lead and the `value=` is a reference to a single field on a single lead.

I don't see why you are using `repeat` at all given that the controller only handles a single Lead and doesn't query any children records

Since the title of your post is `conditional` rendering of stuff, let's try the following:

1. Eliminate the apex:repeat
2. Use this VF in place of your outputPanels

   ```
   <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!lead.Loan_Cost_Net__c >= 0}">
       <apex:outputText value="{0, number, $###,###,###}">
        <apex:param value="{!lead.Loan_Cost_Net__c}"/>
       </apex:outputText>
   </apex:outputPanel>

   <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!lead.Loan_Cost_Net__c < 0}">
     <apex:outputText value="({0, number, - $###,###,###})">
       <apex:param value="{!lead.Loan_Cost_Net__c * -1}"/>
     </apex:outputText>
   </apex:outputPanel>
   ```

Also, and I'd have to check, I thought that the Java output formatting rules will handle the negative sign automatically if value is negative. You should check on that - that would eliminate the need for conditional rendering altogether

Comment: Short answer: I don't know what option is most suitable instead of `repeat`. What should it be?

Comment: @CD-RUM - updated

Comment: Your solution makes total sense but I still get no output at all. Do I need to convert the field from currency to a decimal or something? This is tough because the email preview doesn't generate logs either, so it's like the component isn't even loaded in the preview.

Comment: (1) you do not need to do any conversion, currency fields in apex are decimal ; (2) the reason you may not be seeing anything in Email Template Preview is you have to click the Test and Send button and supply a value for the related to / recipient fields that is a valid Lead Id with a loan Cost Net. The email template preview will render components

Comment: Re (2): yeah, that's done. All the other fields in the email outside the component are populated. Even the same field outside the component is populated. Still nothing.

Comment: Try displaying just a simple `{!lead.loan_cost_net__c}` in the component for debugging as well as `{!lead}`. Try putting Limit 1 on your soql in the controller

Comment: All done, still nothing. Obviously not grabbing a lead, right? Cruising docs I found this wrapping tag: `<messaging:htmlEmailBody>`. Do I need that?

Comment: Goddammit, I'm using a custom template type. I'm guessing I need VF?

Comment: @CD-RUM geez -- glad you found it -- I had assumed this was the case - I should have read your post title more carefully